# Ubuntu 12.04 ethernet not working on an Desktop

Tags: 12.04, ethernet

I am new to ubuntu and just wiped my harddrive to oinstall it on an old desktop.

But I cannot connect to the internet even though the cable is plugged in ( I checked the cable with my laptop and it works fine) Please help me thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As you said it is old desktop.
But even with old one Ethernet card should work.
You should check if LED near LAN connection flashes with green.
If so you probably need to detect connection settings.

You should read about dhcp. It should connect automatically for you.
Unless your ISP provides you with user and password so you need to type it with your IP adress in Network Connections window.